# JavaFX Converting text to hyperlinks in TableView after loading data from xml with JAXB

Tags: javafx, jaxb, tableview, tablecell

Please advise  is there a way to update tableview and set  simple text url  to hyperlink in a table column?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You would use a cell factory for this. The xml/jaxb stuff is irrelevant: it doesn't matter where the data comes from as to how you display it. Try to just create a table view with some hard-coded data, including a URLas the data for a column, and see if you can make it work with a cell factory. Post your actual code if you get stuck.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the tip I tried and it worked! after that I also tried to add XML adapter in the JAXB  and it also worked.

```
public class XMLHyperLinkAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Hyperlink> {

@Override
public Hyperlink unmarshal(String v) {
    try{
        Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
        link.setText(v);
        link.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            link.setVisited(false);
            System.out.println("This link is clicked: " + link.getText());
        });
        return link;

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }

}

@Override
public String marshal(Hyperlink v) throws Exception {
    return v.getText();
}
```

}